# I cannot seem to log in into my main activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-authentication

I cannot log in to my application, and I found no error in the codes. It keeps showing, email is required every time I tried to log in. I connect this app with FireStore as well. So, I need help what did I did wrong here because it supposed to go to the main activity after my login page:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mPassword,mEmail;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    Button mlogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_user);

        final TextView register = findViewById(R.id.register_txt);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password_et);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email_et);
        mlogin = findViewById(R.id.login_bt);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        mlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required");
                    return;

                }
                if(password.length() < 6) {
                    mPassword.setError("6 or more character long");
                    return;
                }
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                         Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                          .show();
                          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
      register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class));
          }
      });
    }
}
```

This is my register, firebase auth, and firestore connected to get information on the users.

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "TAG";
    EditText mfullname, mPassword, mphoneNo, mEmail;
    TextView register;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseFirestore fstore;
    String userID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_user);

    final TextView login = findViewById(R.id.login_text);
    register = findViewById(R.id.register_bt);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email_et);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password_et);
    mfullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname_et);
    mphoneNo = findViewById(R.id.phoneNum_et);


    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String fullName = mfullname.getText().toString();
            String phoneNo = mphoneNo.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                mEmail.setError("Email is required.");
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                mPassword.setError("Password is required");
                return;
            }
            if(password.length() <6){
                mPassword.setError("6 or more character long");
                return;
            }
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Users").document(userID);
                        Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                        user.put("fName",fullName);
                        user.put("email",email);
                        user.put("phone",phoneNo);
                        documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                           Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user profile is created for" + userID);}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                               Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                           }
                       });
                       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<HomeModel> homeModel;
MainAdapter mainAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        selectedFragment = new DashboardFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                        selectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: That's really a lot of code for use to parse through which may lead to downvotes. Can you please isolate the issue and reduce the amount of code? The first step is to focus on your Firebase authentication code - ensure you have proper error handling. If that part is not working, put *that* code in the question and include the error you're receiving. remember - you MUST have error handling or else you won't catch the errors. Please review the following two guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do the login works perfectly the first time? I mean after entering the email and password do you get the toast Login and go to main activity?

Comment: Hello, it did and i can login into main activity before i connect it to firestore.

Comment: Does that mean the issue has been resolved?